# Cookie is only being stored on specific pages

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I wrote a script in JS that will retrieve the traffic source of the user and store that value in a cookie.

For all but three pages this works. If the user's landing page is for example www.example.com/example1, www.example.com/example2 or www.example.com/example3 the cookie gets stored on those pages only. I do not see see it in developer tools on chrome but when I write document.cookie I do see the cookie I created. I also see it in settings.

But if I were to navigate to another page it doesn't get stored.

It works fine on all other pages, the user enters on the landing page and the cookie stays stored during the whole session. Except on the above pages.

The hostname is the same for all pages.

Any ideas?

```js
var source = trafficSource();
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    var source = document.referrer;
}
 
 
function getCookie(name)
  {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }
 
   function checkCookie() {
            var verifyCookie = getCookie("Traffic Source Cookie");
 
            if (verifyCookie != null ){
 
                //alert("there is a cookie");
 
                return "";
            }else{
 
 
               setCookie("Traffic Source Cookie", source, 30);
 
               //alert("new cookie made");
            }
 
    }
 
 
checkCookie();
  var trafficSourceValue = getCookie("Traffic Source Cookie"); // delete if doesnt work
//dataLayer.push( "Cookie Traffic Source is " +getCookie("Traffic Source Cookie"));
 
function trafficSource(trafficType){
 
    var trafficType;
 
        //set traffic sources to variables
        /*var sourceSearchEngine = searchEngine();
         var sourceSocialNetwork = socialNetwork();
        var sourcePaidSearch = paidSearch(); */
 
    // get what kind of referrer
    var trafficReferrer = document.referrer;
    var trafficURL = document.URL;
   
    if(trafficURL.indexOf("gclid") > -1) {
 
 
         trafficType = paidSearch();
 
 
       //alert("paidSearch google");
 
    } else if (trafficURL.indexOf("bing") >-1 &&(trafficURL.indexOf("ppc")> -1) || (trafficURL.indexOf("cpc") >-1)){
 
 
 
        trafficType = paidSearch();
         //alert("paidSearch bing");
    }
 
      else if((trafficReferrer.indexOf("plus.url.google.com")<= 0) && trafficReferrer.indexOf("google")>-1 || trafficReferrer.indexOf("bing")>-1 || trafficReferrer.indexOf("baidu") >-1 || trafficReferrer.indexOf("yahoo") > -1 && (trafficURL.indexOf("ppc") < 0)){
 
 
        trafficType = searchEngine();
        //alert("searchEngine");
 
 
//(trafficReferrer.indexOf("facebook","googleplus", "twitter", "t.co/", "linkedin", "pinterest","reddit","disqus","blogspot.co.uk") >-1
    } else if ((trafficReferrer.indexOf("facebook")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("plus.url.google.com")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("t.co/")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("linkedin")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("reddit")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("disqus")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("blogspot.co.uk")>-1) || (trafficReferrer.indexOf("t.umblr")>-1)) {
 
        trafficType = socialNetwork();
        //alert("socialNetwork");
 
    } else if (trafficReferrer.indexOf("")>-0){
 
        trafficType = directSource();
        //alert("direct");
    }else if (trafficURL.indexOf("display") >-1 || trafficURL.indexOf("Display") >-1){
 
 
        trafficType = display();
        //alert("display");
    }else if (trafficReferrer === "" || trafficReferrer === null){
 
            trafficType = "Direct";
 
    }else {
 
           
 
            //var hostnameReturn = hostname.split("www.");
 
          
             var returnReferrer = document.referrer.match(/https?:\/\/([^\/]*)(?:\/|$)/i)[1].replace(/www\./, "");
            // do I need this snippet
            trafficType =  returnReferrer + "/Referral" ;
 
        //alert("Hostname Referral");
    }
 
    //Return the trafficType which is the function that will get source
    return trafficType;
   // alert("trafficType");
 
}
//setCookie("trafficSource",1,30)
 
//search engine source
function searchEngine (referrer){
            var search = document.referrer;
            var bing = "bing";
            var google ="google";
            var yahoo = "yahoo";
            var ask = "ask";
            var msn = "msn";
            var baidu = "baidu";
            var referrer;
            if (search.indexOf(bing)> -1){
 
                        //alert(bing);
                        referrer = bing + " organic";
            } else if (search.indexOf(yahoo)>-1){
 
                       // alert(bing);
                        referrer = yahoo + " organic";
            } else if (search.indexOf(ask)>-1){
 
                    referrer = ask + " organic";
 
            } else if (search.indexOf(msn)>-1){
 
                       // alert(bing);
                        referrer = msn + " organic";
            } else if (search.indexOf(baidu)>-1){
 
                       // alert(baidu);
                        referrer = baidu + " organic";
            }
             else{
                       // alert(google);
                        referrer = google + " organic";
            }
            return referrer;
           // alert("Search Engine: " + referrer);
           
}
 
//search social network
function socialNetwork (referrer){
 
 
            var search = document.referrer;
            var facebook ="facebook";
            var twitter = "twitter";
            var googlePlus = "google plus";
            var googlePlus2 = "plus.url.google.com";
            var pinterest ="pinterest";
            var linkedin = "linkedin";
            var tumblr = "t.umblr";
            var reddit = "reddit";
            //var beforeItsNews ="news";
            var disquis = "disqus";
            var blogger = "blogspot.co.uk";
            //var StumbleUpon = "StumbleUpon";
            var referrer;
            if(search.indexOf(facebook)> -1){
                       // alert(facebook);
                        referrer = "Social/ " + facebook;
            }else if (search.indexOf(twitter)> -1 || search.indexOf("t.co/") >-1){
                       // alert(twitter);
                        referrer = "Social/ "+ twitter;
            }else if (search.indexOf(pinterest)> -1){
 
                        //alert(pinterest);
                        referrer = "Social/ "+ pinterest;
            }else if (search.indexOf(linkedin) >- 1){
 
                        //alert(linkedin);
                        referrer = linkedin;
 
 
            }else if (search.indexOf(googlePlus) >-1 || search.indexOf(googlePlus2) >-1){
                       // alert(googlePlus);
                        referrer = "Social/ "+ googlePlus;
            }else if (search.indexOf(tumblr) >-1){
                       // alert(googlePlus);
                        referrer ="Social/ "+ "tumblr";
            }else if (search.indexOf(reddit) >-1){
                       // alert(googlePlus);
                        referrer = "Social/ " + reddit;
            }else if (search.indexOf(disquis) >-1){
                       //alert(disquis);
                        referrer = "Social/ "+ disquis;
            }else if (search.indexOf(blogger) >-1){
 
 
                        blogger ="Blogger";
                       //alert(blogger);
                        referrer = "Social/ "+ blogger;
            }else{
 
 
               // alert(document.referrer);
                referrer = "Referral: " + document.referrer;
               // alert("Check Cookie - Referrer");
 
            }
            return referrer;
           // alert("Social Media Network: " + referrer)
}
 
// search for paid search
function paidSearch(referrer){
 
            var paidCampaign = document.URL;
            var campaignReferrer = document.referrer;
            var referrer;
 
            var googleAd = "gclid";
            var justGoogle = "google";
            var justBing = "ppc";
            var bingAd = "Bing";
 
            if (paidCampaign.indexOf(googleAd) >- 1 || campaignReferrer.indexOf(justGoogle) >-1){
 
 
                googleAd = "Google/CPC ";
               // alert(googleAd);
                //referrer = paidCampaign; < original code but trying the code on the bottom>
                referrer = googleAd;
               // alert(referrer);
 
            }
            if (paidCampaign.indexOf(bingAd)>- 1 || paidCampaign.indexOf(justBing) >-1){
 
 
                bingAd = "Bing/CPC ";
                //alert(bingAd);
                referrer = bingAd ;
            }
 
            return referrer;
          //  alert("The paid ad is: " + googleAd);
}
 
function directSource(referrer){
 
 
       var directVistor = document.referrer;
 
 
        if(directVistor ==="" || directVistor === null ){
 
 
            referrer = "Direct";
 
            //alert("Direct");
        }
 
        return referrer;
 
}
 
function display(referrer){
 
    var displayURL = document.URL;
 
    var referrer;
 
   
    if(displayURL.indexOf("display") >- 1 || displayURL.indexOf("Display")>-1){
 
        var returnDisplay = window.location.search.substring(1);
 
        referrer =  "Display: " + returnDisplay;
 
 
 
        //alert(referrer);
 
        return referrer;
    }
 
 
}
 
// function urlSpilt(url){
//     // return utm_source and utm_medium if iti has it.
//     var url;
//     var getURL = document.URL;
//     //var testURL = "http://www.franciscoignacioquintana.com/?utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_campaign=testName";
//     var getURL = getURL.split("utm_source");
//     getURL = getURL[1].split("utm_source");
 
//     url = getURL;
 
//     return url;
// }
 
//http://www.currencies.co.uk/?utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_campaign=testName
 
 
function getQueryParam(par){
 
  //var strURL = document.URL;#
 
  var strURL = document.referrer;
 
  var regParam = new RegExp("(?:\\?|&)" + par + "=([^&$]*)", "i");
 
  var resExp = strURL.match(regParam);
 
  if((typeof resExp == "object") && resExp && (resExp.length > 1)){
 
    return resExp[1];
 
  }
  else{
    return "";
  }
 
}
 
 
//var hostname = window.location.hostname;
 
//var hostnameReturn = hostname.split("www.");
 
//var hostname2 = hostname.slice(4);
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some of your code? Without example code, it gets really difficult to pin down the problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does the cookine by any chance have the "secure" flag?

Comment: I pasted the code. If I enter any other page and there is no cookie it writes a cookies. If  then return assuming same browsers it doesn't overwrite the cookie. Except in 3 specific pages where if I enter again it says there is no cookie and it creates a new cookie but only on those pages.

Comment: You're not setting a path for the cookie (which might explain the behaviour you're seeing but didn't describe very well).

Comment: symcbean thanks I see what you mean. I changed it to the path is root. It appears to be working fine now.